# Map-style parallel processing?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, parallel-processing

I'm trying to do some very simple parallel processing in python. I have a list of data, and I want to compute the exact same thing for each element, and return it as a list, so I looked into some simple map-style modules available (https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing).

I previously used the pprocess module, but it does not seem work this time. I looked into using either forkmap or forkfun, but I haven't really found some nice examples on how to use them.

What would you recommend as the easiest to use map-style parallel processing module? Preferably with a tutorial of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

First off Im not sure having multiple threads would make your program go much faster (but would be curious to see what is the speed up)

I would not use a special tutorial/module and just use basic process/threading stuff
    from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Queue

Output values out of map into the queue (Queue())

```
  processess = []
  results_queue = Queue()
  for i in xrange(50):
    p = Process(target=MyMapFunction, args=tab[i*50:(i+1) * 50])
    processess.append(p)
    p.start()
  # Waiting and Reducing...
  all_key_values = {}
  for _ in xrange(50):
    for k, v in results_queue.get():
      all_key_values.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
  # Some sort of check that threads are done but they should be
  for p in processess:
    p.join()


def MyMapFunction(tab):
  return [(x, 2 * x) for x in tab]
```

I let you do the reduce the same way I did the map and correct the shitty i*50 : (i+1) * 50 that I wrote quickly to give an example
This is the pattern I use when I want to multithread in Python

Comment: ok, is here any advantage in using that approach rather than the Pool from the same module?

And I'm not sure what you want filled in, could you maybe expand the example with some simple function?